# Subtotals and grand total above table in R using gt()

Tags: r, dplyr, gt

As you know R operates with columns pretty well. However, with rows might be difficult. On the other hand, Excel rows are nice, especially subtotals.
To solve my problem, I need to implement Excel style to R tables.

Important things, are subtotals and grand totals. Subtotals above the table subgroup, and grand totals above the first subgroup.
Is it possible to adapt code from the [gt() reference](https://gt.rstudio.com/reference/summary_rows.html), to put subtotals above groups, instead of ALL display labels from tab_row_group, and formatting that entirely summary row. This example missed ALL.
Thanks.

```
library(gt)

countrypops |>
  dplyr::filter(
    country_code_2 %in% c("BR", "RU", "IN", "CN", "FR", "DE", "IT", "GB")
  ) |>
  dplyr::filter(year %% 10 == 0) |>
  dplyr::select(country_name, year, population) |>
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = year, values_from = population) |>
  gt(rowname_col = "country_name") |>
  tab_row_group(
    label = md("*BRIC*"),
    rows = c("Brazil", "Russian Federation", "India", "China"),
    id = "bric"
  ) |>
  tab_row_group(
    label = md("*Big Four*"),
    rows = c("France", "Germany", "Italy", "United Kingdom"),
    id = "big4"
  ) |>
  row_group_order(groups = c("bric", "big4")) |>
  tab_spanner(columns = everything(), label = "Year") |>
  fmt_number(n_sigfig = 3, suffixing = TRUE) |>
  summary_rows(
    fns =  list(label = md("**ALL**"), id = "totals", fn = "sum"),
    fmt = ~ fmt_number(., n_sigfig = 3, suffixing = TRUE),
    side = "top"
  ) |>
  tab_style(
    locations = cells_summary(),
    style = cell_fill(color = "lightblue" |> adjust_luminance(steps = +1))
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(gt)

countrypops |>
  dplyr::filter(
    country_code_2 %in% c("BR", "RU", "IN", "CN", "FR", "DE", "IT", "GB")
  ) |>
  dplyr::filter(year %% 10 == 0) |>
  dplyr::select(country_name, year, population) |>
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = year, values_from = population) |>
  gt(rowname_col = "country_name") |>
  tab_row_group(
    label = md("*BRIC*"),
    rows = c("Brazil", "Russian Federation", "India", "China"),
    id = "bric"
  ) |>
  tab_row_group(
    label = md("*Big Four*"),
    rows = c("France", "Germany", "Italy", "United Kingdom"),
    id = "big4"
  ) |>
  row_group_order(groups = c("bric", "big4")) |>
  tab_spanner(columns = everything(), label = "Year") |>
  fmt_number(n_sigfig = 3, suffixing = TRUE) |>
  summary_rows(
    fns =  list(label = md("Subgroup Total"), id = "totals", fn = "sum"),
    fmt = ~ fmt_number(., n_sigfig = 3, suffixing = TRUE),
    side = "top"
  ) |>
  tab_style(
    locations = cells_summary(),
    style = cell_fill(color = "lightblue" |> adjust_luminance(steps = +1))
  ) |>
  grand_summary_rows(
    columns = c('1960', '1970', '1980', '1990', '2000', '2010', '2020'),
    fns = list(
      'Grand Total' ~ sum(.)
    ),
    , 
    side = 'top',
    fmt = ~ fmt_number(., n_sigfig = 3, suffixing = TRUE)
  ) |>
  tab_style(
    locations = cells_grand_summary(),
    style = cell_fill(color = "lightblue" |> adjust_luminance(steps = +1))
  )
```

[image: sample]

Comment: Yes, except I would like to have BRIC in the first Subgroup total, and Big four in the second. In addition same format to be applied to that text, as for the numbers in the row (blue background in the Bric cell). Tnks.

Comment: I am not sure about the differentiated subgroup summary labels, but the formatting is approachable. I have adjusted my response above to meet your formatting needs.

Comment: Thank I will implement and check as a solution for my problem. Thanks.